# Python 3 rounding issue

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

Why is the below rounding not working in python 3 but only in python 2?

```
random_nums = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
probabilities = np.array([0.01, 0.3, 0.58, 0.1, 0.01])
target = dict(zip(random_nums, probabilities))
target = {k: round(v, 2) for k, v in target.items()}

out:
{-1: 0.01,
 0: 0.29999999999999999,
 1: 0.57999999999999996,
 2: 0.10000000000000001,
 3: 0.01}
```

Comment: If you need exact rounding with floats/doubles, do the rounding when converting to string for output. Due to the number of digits displayed, that's as close as the chosen floating point precision gets to those numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working with NumPy `float64` objects instead of Python `float` objects. This has a few consequences:

1. On Python 3, `float64` objects are rounded using NumPy's rounding code instead of Python's. Python's rounding code for `float`s always gives correctly-rounded results. NumPy's rounding code does not. (On Python 2, it's not possible to override the `round` operation for custom types, so when you round a `float64` object in Python 2 it first gets converted to a Python `float`, and then Python's rounding code is used to give a `float` result. This is the main reason that you're seeing a difference between Python 2 and Python 3.)
2. Again on Python 3, because of the above, `round` on a `float64` gives a `float64` result. On Python 2, `round` on a `float64` object gives a `float` result.
3. Python `float` objects have a different `repr`, which will give pleasanter output. In particular, Python's float `repr` guarantees roundtripping for (not too large, not too small) decimal values with at most 15 significant figures: the representation of `0.58` is `'0.58'`, for example. The representation of NumPy `float64` objects does not have this property: it just prints out a result based on the most significant 17 decimal digits of the stored value.

So if you convert your values to Python `float` objects before the round, you'll see pleasanter output (and in some cases, the results may be a tiny bit more accurate). But note that just because the output looks nice, that doesn't mean that the results you're getting are exact. None of this changes the fact that `0.58` is *not* exactly representable as a Python `float` (or indeed a NumPy `float64`, which uses the same format). Remember, with binary floating-point, What You See Is Not What You Get.

Some example output on Python 3:

```
>>> random_nums = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> probabilities = np.array([0.01, 0.3, 0.58, 0.1, 0.01])
>>> target = dict(zip(random_nums, probabilities))
>>> {k: round(v, 2) for k, v in target.items()}
{0: 0.29999999999999999, 1: 0.57999999999999996, 2: 0.10000000000000001, 3: 0.01, -1: 0.01}
>>> {k: round(float(v), 2) for k, v in target.items()}
{0: 0.3, 1: 0.58, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.01, -1: 0.01}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine. Remember, `round` returns a floating-point number.

It rounded to two decimals, but floats are inherently inprecise (for almost all the numbers), hence the output.

Comment: so the output looks nice and has only 2 decimals

Comment: If you want floating-point output, then that's the best you can do. *There's nothing wrong with it*. If you want to *print* it (string representation), that's another issue.